# How to query multiple rows from EAV table design?

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I have a situation where I have to use EAV table design.

I have the following two tables.

**Nodes**

```
id    name    structure_id
 1    name 1       7
 2    name 2       7
```

**Attributes**

```
id    node_id    name       value    structure_id
1       1        firstname  test         7
2       1        lastname   test         7
3       2        firstname  test         7
```

I have the following query

```
SELECT n.*, GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS('||', a.name, a.value) ORDER BY a.name SEPARATOR ';;' ) as _attributes
            FROM nodes n JOIN attributes a ON n.structure_id = a.structure_id where n.structure_id = 7
```

The above query outputs the following (only ONE row)

```
id: 1
name: name 1
structure_id: 7
_attributes: firstname||test;;firstname||test;;firstname||test;;firstname||test;;lastname||test;;lastname||test
```

How do I make it to output two rows from **nodes** table with their rows from **attributes**?

Comment: Change `ORDER BY a.name` to `GROUP BY a.name`. Alternatively, you can add `GROUP BY node_id` clause too.

Comment: @BackinaFlash // Hi, I've tried both of them. didn't work..

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ebd1/18 seems to be generating a little bit good result. It still has all values from attributes table though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will obtain desired result set if join nodes and attributes tables by structure_id and node_id. 
Desired result set: "from nodes table with their rows from attributes" .

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83643/1

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
select n.id,n.name,n.structure_id,firstname,lastname from Nodes n 
join (select node_id, a.value as firstname from Attributes a where a.name='firstname' ) matches1 on matches1.node_id = n.id 
left join (select node_id, a.value as lastname  from Attributes a where a.name='lastname' )  matches2 on matches2.node_id = n.id
```

Comment: Thanks..but it needs to be dynamic. I can't hardcode 'firstname'